# Create multiple DataGrids in WPF dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to dynamically create `DataGrid`s in WPF, one below the other in a `Grid`. the problem is that I don't even know where to start, I saw that it could be done through code but I would like to use XAML correctly.

```
void PopulateDatagridSQL(string Data, string index, string TabName)
{
   try
   {
      Data = Data.Replace((Char)6, (Char)124);

      List<DataTable> Results = new List<DataTable>();

      Results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataTable>>(Data);
      foreach (SQLWindow SingleSQLWindows in StaticVar.MySQLWindows)
      {
         if (SingleSQLWindows.MyINDEX == index)
         {
            SingleSQLWindows.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
               foreach (TabItem item in SingleSQLWindows._tabItems)
               {
                  if (item.Name == TabName)
                  {
                     //create multiple datagrids up to results.count
                     ((SQLPage)((Frame)item.Content).Content).DataGrid1.ItemsSource = Results[0].DefaultView;//foreach
                     ((SQLPage)((Frame)item.Content).Content).TxtSqlLog.Text = "Records in Datagrid: " + Results[0].Rows.Count;//foreach
                  }
               }
            }));
         }
      }
   }
   catch (Exception asd)
   {

      foreach (SQLWindow SingleSQLWindows in StaticVar.MySQLWindows)
      {
         if (SingleSQLWindows.MyINDEX == index)
         {
            SingleSQLWindows.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
               foreach (TabItem item in SingleSQLWindows._tabItems)
               {
                  if (item.Name == TabName)
                  {
                     ((SQLPage)((Frame)item.Content).Content).TxtSqlLog.Text = "Error in $SqlResponse";
                  }
               }
            }));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In this function I receive a list of `DataTable`s and for each `DataTable` I have to create a `DataGrid`.

```
<Page x:Class="Emergency_APP_Server_WPF.Forms.SQLPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Emergency_APP_Server_WPF.Forms"
  mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="SQLPageXaml" Loaded="SQLPage_Loaded"
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="SQLPage" >

<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="100"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="0"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="150"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <avalonEdit:TextEditor Grid.Column="0" Background="White"
            xmlns:avalonEdit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"  
            Name="MyAvalonEdit" FontFamily="Consolas"
            FontSize="11pt" Margin="10,10,10,10" ShowLineNumbers="True"
            LineNumbersForeground="Gray" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" KeyUp="MyAvalonEdit_KeyUp"/>
            <Button  Grid.Column="1" x:Name="BtnSendSQL" Margin="0,10,10,10" Click="BtnSendSQL_Click">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Height="25" Source="..//Resources/send.png"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Text="SendSQL"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <GridSplitter Margin="0,-10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext">
        </GridSplitter>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="DataGrid1" RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowSql}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyleSQL}" >
            <DataGrid.CommandBindings>
                <CommandBinding Command="Copy" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"></CommandBinding>
            </DataGrid.CommandBindings>
            <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="Copy"></KeyBinding>
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>
        </DataGrid>
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="TxtSqlLog" Text="Wait For Commands..."
                   FontSize="14" FontFamily="Consolas" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the exact layout where you want to put all the `DataGrid`s, so I just assume you want to place them in row `2` of your `Grid`. As you want to stack them, you can use an `ItemsControl` in a `ScrollViewer`. The latter is just there, so you can scroll through the `DataGrids` in case the page is too small to display them all. So this is the basic layout for the solutions below.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <!-- ...your row definitions. -->
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <!-- ...your other controls. -->
   <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
      <ItemsControl/>
   </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

### Code-behind solution

In code-behind, you need to access the `ItemsControl`, so assign it a name.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="DataGridContainer"/>
```

Then just create `DataGrid`s in a loop from your `DataTable` list.

```
foreach (var dataTable in Results)
{
   var dataGrid = new DataGrid { ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView };
   DataGridContainer.Items.Add(dataGrid);
};
```

By the way, in this scenario, you could also use a `StackPanel` instead of an `ItemsControl`.

### MVVM solution

You can create a property in your view model that exposes the default views of your `DataTables`.

```
public ObservableCollection<DataView> DataViews { get; }
```

Make sure you instantiate the collection in the constructor or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so that the collection is available in XAML. Then bind the `ItemsControl` to this collection.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataViews}"/>
```

Next create a `DataTemplate` for the `DataView` type. As each data view in the bound collection represents a data table that should be displayed as a `DataGrid`, it would look like this.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:DataView}">
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you have to assign this data template as `ItemTemplate` in the `ItemsControl`. I just inline it here, but you can also put it in any `ResourceDictionary` and reference it via `StaticResource`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataViews}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:DataView}">
         <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now, you just have to add the default views to the `DataView`s collection. As this collection is an `ObservableCollection`, it will notify the `ItemsControl` to update on each add.

```
foreach (var dataTable in Results)
{
   DataViews.Add(dataTable.DefaultView);
};
```

As an item is added, the `ItemsControl` will get notified and creates an item using the `DataTemplate`.

I recommend you to use the MVVM solution, as it separates the presentation from your data and is much easier to realize and customization of the `DataGrid`s via the `DataTemplate` is much easier, convenient and maintainable in XAML.

Comment: i have a problem :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<Page x:Class="Emergency_APP_Server_WPF.Forms.SQLPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:z="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Emergency_APP_Server_WPF.Forms"
  mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="SQLPageXaml" Loaded="SQLPage_Loaded"
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="SQLPage" >

<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="100"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="0"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="150"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <avalonEdit:TextEditor Grid.Column="0" Background="White"
            xmlns:avalonEdit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"  
            Name="MyAvalonEdit" FontFamily="Consolas"
            FontSize="11pt" Margin="10,10,10,10" ShowLineNumbers="True"
            LineNumbersForeground="Gray" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" KeyUp="MyAvalonEdit_KeyUp"/>
            <Button  Grid.Column="1" x:Name="BtnSendSQL" Margin="0,10,10,10" Click="BtnSendSQL_Click">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Height="25" Source="..//Resources/send.png"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Text="SendSQL"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <GridSplitter Margin="0,-10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext">
        </GridSplitter>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataViews}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type z:DataView}">
                        <DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowSql}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyleSQL}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                            <DataGrid.CommandBindings>
                                <CommandBinding Command="Copy" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"></CommandBinding>
                            </DataGrid.CommandBindings>
                            <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                                <KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="Copy"></KeyBinding>
                            </DataGrid.InputBindings>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="TxtSqlLog" Text="Wait For Commands..."
                   FontSize="14" FontFamily="Consolas" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

```
 public ObservableCollection<DataView> _DataViews = new ObservableCollection<DataView>();
    public ObservableCollection<DataView> DataViews
    {
        get
        {
            return _DataViews;
        }
        set
        {
            _DataViews = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string Param = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Param));
    }


foreach (SQLWindow SingleSQLWindows in StaticVar.MySQLWindows)
            {
                if (SingleSQLWindows.MyINDEX == index)
                {
                    SingleSQLWindows.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        foreach (TabItem item in SingleSQLWindows._tabItems)
                        {
                            if (item.Name == TabName)
                            {
                                foreach (DataTable itemTable in Results)
                                {
                                    //SingleSQLWindows.DataViews.Add(itemTable.DefaultView);

                                    ////create more datagrid while results.count
                                    ///
                                    ((SQLPage)((Frame)item.Content).Content).DataViews.Add(itemTable.DefaultView);
                                    //((SQLPage)((Frame)item.Content).Content).TxtSqlLog.Text = "Records in Datagrid: " + Results[0].Rows.Count;//foreach
                                }



                            }
                        }
                    }));
                }
            }
```

the visual studio does not report any errors but the scrollviewer remains empty, I cannot understand why

Comment: Did it work before or did you not get it working at all? Please check at runtime, if the `DataViews` collection has any items, e.g. add a breakpoint after you fill the list. Check your ouput if there are any binding errors. I am not sure if you add to the `DataView`s collection correctly in this line `((SQLPage)((Frame)item.Content).Content).DataViews.Add(itemTable.DefaultView);`, it looks suspicious. Furthermore you apply styles which may cause an issue. Try without them, too.

Comment: never work , I thought it would work - i remove RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowSql}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyleSQL}" but nothing....... and in this screen you can see DataViews count, i have also tryed to stop on return _DataViews; and it stop! then the code passes there. any suggestion?  link to image DataView   [IMAGE](https://ibb.co/4j6L36f)

Comment: What about the output, does it show any errors like binding errors?

Comment: nothing , only empty, nothing errors :| see image [IMAGE](https://ibb.co/JWJ4dVJ)

Comment: Try to put only the `ScrollViewer` with its controls in the Grid or on the `Page` to see if it is not displayed due to a wrong layout. As there are no binding errors and the `DataViews` property is popuplated, it just does not seem to be displayed.

Comment: if you look the image on previuous comment you can see the scrollviewview , is where i designed a red circle , the empy zone with only scroll bar , the scroll viewer is visibile but empy , i change the control datagrid with a textblock for example , its the same , empty.

Comment: What if you put a `TextBlock` directly into the scroll viewer without the items control, is it displayed?

Comment: What happens if you remove `DataType="{x:Type z:DataView}"` from the `DataTemplate`?
Additionally, use the `TextBlock` and bind the `DataViews.Count` property to its `Text` to see if it has any items or if the collection was just not refreshed, e.g. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataViews.Count}"/>`.

Comment: nothing , empty..... nothing errors but again empty, i have re-control _DataViews and its ok , see [IMAGE](https://ibb.co/kyxg0Rv) ------------- ok i try with textblock

Comment: nothing :(     -    
[IMAGE](https://ibb.co/LhSwwFb)
   -       
[IMAGE](https://ibb.co/MStfbx2)

Comment: Please bind it directly `<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataViews.Count}"/>` not through the backing field `_DataViews`, that seems to be ok.

Comment: I meant you should add this text block instead of the items control directly in the scroll viewer.

Comment: nothing, even with this modification remains empty, it is as if itemscontrol did not work

Comment: Just as a quick check, replace the getter of  `DataViews` with `get { return _dataViews ??= new ObservableCollection<DataView>(); }` and test again.

Comment: [image1](https://ibb.co/w6T1B3f) - [image2](https://ibb.co/mSCMngH)

all work , but empty ...... i dont understand

Comment: I think you should really try this an empty project just for the core of this question. There is definitely something wrong with your `DataViews` property or the data context. Your view structure is complex and from this limited view it is nearly impossible to guess what the problem actually is. This is also beyond the scope of this question, as it is a different problem.